# How can I make a bool reference argument defaulted?

Tags: c++, arguments, default-value

In C++, is it possible to make a `bool &` argument of a function optional?

```
void foo(bool &argument = /* What goes here? */);
```

In my function foo, if the caller does not care about the result put into argument, I'd like the compiler to give a dummy location by default. Otherwise, callers who do not care must do this:

```
bool ignored;

foo(ignored);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make another function

```
void foo(){
  bool b=true;
  foo(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to pass a global variable :

```
bool someArgument = false;

void foo(bool &argument = someArgument );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. But it is very ugly and messes up data locality:

```
static bool result__ = false;

static void foo(bool & result = result__)
{
        result = true;
}

int main()
{
        bool v;
        foo();
        foo(v);
        return v ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Since C++ supports function overloading, use @QuentinUK's solution.

Comment: Clever trick.  I agree that @QuentinUK's solution with function overloading is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be using a function overload instead of trying to work around the system. Although there are legitimate ways to achieve this like the one @VJovic mentioned. With function overloads you can make other parameters optional too if ever you need to add more.

Answer (score 0):

A non-const reference argument means your function intends to modify the object being passed.  If you know which object you want that to be by default, then just use it as the default argument.

If you do not intend to modify the `bool` being passed in, then you should declare the function to take `bool argument` (i.e. not a reference) or `const bool &argument`.  In either case you can provide a constant default value of true or false.